# Multi filter in Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is what I am looking to do. I have a data list with Supervisor/Agent/Script. the formula I am trying to build pulls per supervisor and script to show how many agents under a supervisor used a specific script
example below:

[image]

[image]

so in the example John had 2 agents that used S1 and 1 agent that used S2.
I could write this in VBA easily but the ask is for a formula.

Thanks!

Comment: This will depend on which version of Excel you have.

Comment: Office 365 ProPlus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use three formula:

In F1:

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(C2:C13))
```

In E2:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A13)
```

In F2:

```
=COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(MATCH($B$2:$B$14,$B$2:$B$14,0),($A$2:$A$14=$E2)*($C$2:$C$14=F$1),"a")))
```

and copy over and down.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this much cleaner via PivotTable if that is an option.

Just make sure that when you insert the Pivot Table you select *Add this data to the Data Model*.

Then add the Script to Columns; Supervisor to Rows; and Agent to Values. Select Value Field Settings for Agent and change the *summarize value field by* to **Distinct Count**.

[PivotTable Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNPkx.png)